# How to install Mysql on oracle Virtual box which has Opensuse OS

Tags: mysql, virtualbox

We have an open suse image on Virtual Box, which doesn't have mysql libraries. Can we install mysql libraries onto that image ? If so how ??  Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with yast2 or yast GUI:

`yast2 -i mysql mysql-client mysql-community-server`

Alternatively, you can also install with RPM/DEB or generic binary package as described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation.html